# How can I use jQuery to trigger a form submit?

Tags: jquery, forms

Consider this form:

HTML:

```
<form action="my_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadFile" target="hiddenIframe">
    <input type="file" name="files" id="files">
    <input id="fileUploadButton" type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload File">
    <iframe name="hiddenIframe" id="hiddenIFrame"></iframe>
</form>
<div id="myButton" onclick="submitFile()">Submit</div>
<input type="hidden" id="fileID" value="">
```

The following jQuery script will allow me to upload the file:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#fileUploadButton').click(function(){
            $('#uploadFile').submit();
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

After the script is run the id (from the database) of the newly uploaded file is inserted into the hidden input field with `id="fileID"` All of this works fine. However, what I want to do is trigger the above form submission by clicking on `<div id="myButton">`

```
function submitFile() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('input[name=files]').val() != "")
        {
            $('#uploadFile').submit(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'my_file.php',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#fileID').val(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I'm unable to get the above script to work. The file upload form is NOT submitted. Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

**UPDATE:**
I removed `onclick="submitFile()"` from the button and tried this, but it doesn't work. Why?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(document).on('click','#myButton',function(){
            $('#uploadFile').submit(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'my_file2.php',
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#fileID').val(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

UPDATE 2: If I click on the file submit button (`id="fileUploadButton"`), then the form is submitted in the iframe, as it should be. But, if I try to use my updated script (from UPDATE:... above) to submit the form by clicking on the button (`id="myButton"`), then it doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you putting `.ready()` within a function? Also, wouldn't it make sense to put the `if` statement within the `.submit` statement?

Comment: You should use `return false` on the click. You can also use `console.log('test');` to see if the click works and submit, comment out the `ajax()`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

If you look in the browsers console, can you see the logs?

```
$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function() {
   console.log('click');
   $('#uploadFile').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log('submit');
   });

   return false
});
```

---

Try this using `on()` instead, also depends if you want to do a postback of the page then you dont need the `on()` and `ajax`

```
$('#uploadFile').on('click', function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'my_file.php',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#fileID').val(data);
                    }
                });

        return false;
 });
```

Comment: I tried an updated script that I added above, but it doesn't work. I can't figure out why.

Comment: No error. The form just isn't submitting. The file is not stored in the database, and the file id is not stored in the ``id="fileID"`` hidden field. But I know my php script works, so it can't be that. For some reason, the updated jquery script that I added simply is not submitting the form (``$('#uploadFile').submit(function(){``...).

Comment: Note that a fileupload does not work with ajax, you can read this tutorial that uses php http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/, or just use the plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any event handler in the first place; an `<input type="submit">` is already going to submit the form. As for the other button, just have it do what you originally had for the first button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myButton').click(function() {
        $('#uploadFile').submit();
    });

    $('#uploadFile').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'my_file.php',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#fileID').val(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Then you attach the submit handler at the same time as you attach the click handler. No handlers are attached dynamically here.

To stress the point: **`#fileUploadButton` doesn’t need JavaScript to do what it does naturally.**

P.S. Don’t you want your Ajax request to actually contain something?